# makefile : missing separator

Tags: linux, makefile

```
#kernel build system and can use its lanauge
ifneq($(KERNELRELEASE),)
 obj-m:=helloworld.o
else
 KDIR:= /lib/modules/2.6.33.3-85.fc13.i686/build
all:
 make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
 rm -f *.ko *.o *.mod.o *.mod.c *.symvers
endif
```

The error is:

> makefile:2:*** missing separator . stop

but for the `ifneq($(KERNELRELEASE),)`, if I add a tab before, I get another error:

> makefile:2: ***commands commence before first target. stop

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There must be a space between `ifneq` and `(`.

The TAB prefix means that it is a shell command, so be sure that the shell commands (`make` and `rm`) begin with TAB, and all other lines such as `ifneq` do not begin with TAB.

Answer (score 1):

Make is complaining that the second line doesn't start with a tab. Your IDE/texteditor may be saving the file using spaces as equivalent to a tab character. Either configure the IDE to use the tab character, or use a simple editor like vim or nano and replace the leading white space on the second line with a tab.

Answer (score 0):

Check before `obj-m:` and `KDIR:` etc. Are your tabs being inserted as spaces?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the second part of your conditional ifneq($(KERNELRELEASE),) needs to have something after the comma, like "2.6.17" (for example).