# I can not figure it out what's wrong in this makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to compile a C library for genetic programming called [lil-gp](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39371917/lilgp1.1.tar.gz).

I do not know if this kind of questions are appropriate to ask here but i am seeking serious help about this.

The makefile resides under the directory `lilgp1.1/1.1/kernel` and named as `GNUmakefile.kernel`. And it looks like this:

```
kobjects = main.o gp.o eval.o tree.o change.o crossovr.o reproduc.o \
    mutate.o select.o tournmnt.o bstworst.o fitness.o genspace.o \
    exch.o populate.o ephem.o ckpoint.o event.o pretty.o individ.o \
    params.o random.o memory.o output.o

kheaders = event.h defines.h types.h protos.h protoapp.h

.PHONY : all clean

LIBS += -lm
CFLAGS += -I. -I$(KERNELDIR) 

all : $(TARGET)

lilgp.h = $(addprefix $(KERNELDIR)/,$(kheaders)) $(uheaders)

$(kobjects) : %.o : $(KERNELDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(uobjects) : %.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(kobjects) $(uobjects) : $(lilgp.h)

$(TARGET) : $(kobjects) $(uobjects)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS) 

clean :
    \rm -f $(kobjects) $(uobjects) core
```

As a first move I followed these steps:

1. I renamed it as `Makefile`
2. Second i moved `all : $(TARGET)` just above to the `clean: ...`

But GNU make complains me that :

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/main.c', needed by `main.o'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Is there a makefile in the directories above kernel - they will probably define KERNELDIR

Comment: Seems that the link to the project ftp site is dead. I uploaded it to another location. Please check it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: read the documentation that's included in the package (especially chapters 3 and 6).

Longer answer: if you would have read the documentation, you would have known that you're not supposed to use `GNUmakefile.kernel` directly. You need to choose one of the sample apps in the package and run make in its directory. Each one of the apps directories contains a (short) `GNUmakefile` that includes `GNUmakefile.kernel`.
Alternatively, you can implement your own problem, by providing your own top level Makefile.

Comment: Actually i had read it up to 3.1 and also 3.4; that's a pity that i did not realised the actual part that MUST be read is between. Anyway, thanks for your useful comments and critics.

Answer (score 3):

From the error message it seems clear that `$(KERNELDIR)` is blank. I would grep the entire project tree for the word `KERNELDIR` and take it from there...

Answer (score 1):

The following line is trying to access the first file in the `kobjects` which is `main.c` and it is unsuccessful because `KERNELDIR` may not be set.

```
$(kobjects) : %.o : $(KERNELDIR)/%.c
```

With a quick scan, everything else seems to be fine.

Please be careful when attempting to modify a Makefile to ensure that you don't run into problems like [missing-separator-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315108/makefile-missing-separator)